# C++ does not find QML StackView

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I need to push a qml page to stackview from other qml page.
So i am using c++-qml interacting for this problem.
my c++ code finds page item, but does not find stackView.

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...

    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));
    QObject* object = component.create();

    Settings::defineObject(object);
    return app.exec();
}
```

settings.h:

```
class Settings : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    static QObject* object;
public:
    ...
    Q_INVOKABLE void push(QString fileName);
    static void defineObject(QObject* obj);
};
```

settings.cpp:

```
QObject* Settings::object = nullptr;

...

void Settings::push(QString fileName)
{
    if (Settings::object == nullptr) QCoreApplication::exit(-3);
    QObject* page = Settings::object->findChild<QObject*>("page");

    if (!page) QCoreApplication::exit(-4);
    QObject* stackView = page->findChild<QObject*>("stackView");

    if (!stackView) QCoreApplication::exit(-5);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(stackView, "push", Q_ARG(QString, fileName));
}

void Settings::defineObject(QObject* obj)
{
    object = obj;
}
```

main.qml:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    ...

    Page {
        id: page
        ...

       StackView {
            id: stackView
            initialItem: "Home.qml"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

**My program always exits -5 code.**

Comment: `findChild` looks for items by `name`,  so you have to define `objectName:"stackView"` for your `StackView` item. `id` is a kind of pointer in C++, just a variable name.

Comment: Yes! It's running! Thanks.